# MS Office Lock-File (owner file) behavior differs between Netdrive and Synced-Folders (Nextcloud)

Tags: synchronization, ms-office, nextcloud

I have a strange behavior of MS Word/Office/Visio when opening files that are already opend by another User.

- Nextcloud 12.0.3
- Sync-Client 2.3.3.1
- All Clients: Windows 7

Situation A (working as intended):

- test.doc file located on a network drive x:
- User A opens test.doc with MS Word 2010
- a hidden lock-file (owner file) is createt named ~$test.doc
- User B can open that lock-file in Nodepad++ and read User A's username
- User B opens test.doc and get a message, that the file is already in use by User A

Situation B (not working):

- test.doc file is located in a folder which gets synced by the Nextcloud Sync-Client
- Sync-Clinet is configured to sync hidden files
- snyc-exclude.lst is altered to sync MS Office lock-files (owner-files)
- User A opens test.doc file with MS Word 2010
- a hidden lock-file (owner file) is createt named ~$test.doc
- the lock-file gets synced over to User B's Nextcloud Sync-Folder
- User B can open that lock-file in Nodepad++ and read User A's username
- User B opens test.doc, NO "already in use" message is shown
- Both users can edit and save the document without any warning

I really don't understand why Word recognises the lock-file in situation A and ignores the file in situation B.
I must use the nextcloud sync-client and i also need to make sure, that file locking works. Collabora is no option.
Does anyone have a hint or solution for this problem, or can explain why office behaves like that?

desperat greetings,

ichnafi

**UPDATE:**
So, for everyone who is interested in my little wrapper, I set up an Github repository:

https://github.com/Ichnafi/NC-Office-Wrapper

It's under MIT Licence, so feel free to do what ever you like with it. If you make it better, please share it with the community.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So,
since none here or in the Nextcloud community seems to have a better idea of how to fix/mitigate my problem, I "fixed" it myself.
I wrote a wrapper in .NET that checks for office lock-files. This tool is now the standard application for Word/Excel/Visio files.

Cheers!

Comment: Aaaany chance you opensourced that wrapper?

Comment: I will put the code on Github or so, but have to clean up some company regarding stuff first, that I'm not allowed to share. I try to do that this weekend.